# How to extract specfic rows from a dataframe

Tags: r

Suppose I have sufficiently large dataframe with about a million rows

And I want to remove the rows between BSM and ENDBSM in a dataframe how can I do it efficiently?

I thought to first mark the rows with 1 which I need to extract using following loop but it's taking forever.

```
chkSTR = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(rDATA)){

  if(rDATA$Data[i] == "BSM"){
    chkSTR = 1
  }

  if(rDATA$Data[i] == "ENDBSM"){
    chkSTR = 0
  }

  rDATA$BOOL[i] = chkSTR

}
```

Input data frame example

```
rData = data.frame(

Data = 

c(1,"BSM","a",3,3,"ENDBSM",1,3,1,"BSM","b",3,3,"ENDBSM",1,2,1,"BSM","c",2,3,"ENDBSM",1,2)

)


Output example

rData = data.frame(

Data = 

c("BSM","a",3,3,"ENDBSM","BSM","b",3,3,"ENDBSM","BSM","c",2,3,"ENDBSM")

)
```

Comment: Take a look at [`filter`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) from `dplyr`.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` to make a *flip flop* between BSM and ENDBSM. No need that the number of BSM and ENDBSM are the same and no need that BSM comes first. It simple turns on when BSM comes and turns of when ENDBSM comes.

```
idx <- Reduce(function(y,x) {(y || x=="BSM") && x!= "ENDBSM"}, x=rData$Data, init=FALSE, accumulate=TRUE)
rData[idx[-1] | idx[-length(idx)], , drop = FALSE]
#     Data
#2     BSM
#3       a
#4       3
#5       3
#6  ENDBSM
#10    BSM
#11      b
#12      3
#13      3
#14 ENDBSM
#18    BSM
#19      c
#20      2
#21      3
#22 ENDBSM
```

In case you want to get rid of the surrounding BSM and ENDBSM you can do this with:

```
rData[idx[-1] & idx[-length(idx)], , drop = FALSE]
#   Data
#3     a
#4     3
#5     3
#11    b
#12    3
#13    3
#19    c
#20    2
#21    3
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the number of `"BSM"` of `"ENDBSM"` are same and `"BSM"` always comes first we can use `mapply` and create a sequence between indices to subset.

```
rData[c(mapply(`:`, which(rData$Data == "BSM"), 
                    which(rData$Data == "ENDBSM"))), , drop = FALSE]
#    Data
#2     BSM
#3       a
#4       3
#5       3
#6  ENDBSM
#10    BSM
#11      b
#12      3
#13      3
#14 ENDBSM
#18    BSM
#19      c
#20      2
#21      3
#22 ENDBSM
```

Comment: there can be many c and f and assumption that c always comes first before f is true also there is always a f for every c

Comment: Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: @anal works fine for me for the input data you shared. Do you face the error on the same data or some other data?

Comment: > class(rDATA)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(rDATA$Data)
[1] "character"


these are the classes of rDATA and rDATA$Data  is the class reason?

Comment: No...that should not be an issue. I have the same classes and it is working. Check `length(which(rData$Data == "BSM"))` and same for "ENDBSM" are they equal? Also check the indices are they in the range of rows?

Comment: length is same 

`> length(which(rDATA$Data == "BSM"))
[1] 35832`

`> length(which(rDATA$Data == "ENDBSM"))
[1] 35832`

Comment: @anal that is strange. Can you confirm if `range(c(which(rData$Data == "BSM"), which(rData$Data == "ENDBSM")))` both are between 1 and `nrow(rData)` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(which(rData$Data == "BSM"), which(rData$Data == "ENDBSM"), `:`) %>%
     flatten_int %>%
     extract2(rData, ., )
```

Comment: missing argument to a function call in the last line